# Pre-Select the only item in dropdown AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create an attribute directive (because I need to use this logic at multiple places in my project) for Select dropdown which automatically selects the only item if the items array has only one element.
I have the following HTML with an attribute directive named `smart-select-dropdown`:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedItem" smart-select-dropdown
          ng-options="item as item.name for item in items | filter: {someFilter}">
    <option value="" ng-bind="Select Item"></option>
</select>
```

Here is my directive code:

```
angular.module('app').directive('smartSelectDropDown', function(){
   return{
      restrict: 'A',
      replace: true,
      link: function(scope, element){
         angular.element(document).ready(function () {
                if(element[0].options.length === 2){
                    element.find('select option:nth-child(2)').prop('selected', true);
                }
         });
      }
   }
});
```

Here is the controller code:

```
angular.module('app').controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){
   $scope.selectedItem = null;
   $scope.items = [
                    { 
                      id : 1,
                      name : 'Item 1'
                    },
                    { 
                      id : 2,
                      name : 'Item 2'
                    },
                    { 
                      id : 3,
                      name : 'Item 3'
                    }
                  ];
});
```

The problem I am facing is that `element[0].options.length` is not giving me the correct length. It is always giving me 1 which is actually the default 'Select Item' option. It does not contain the length of `ng-options` which is actually required. Can anyone let me know what am I missing here?

PS: I am using AngularJS version 1.2.17

Comment: Can you post some more code, specially in your controller, where you have items and selectedItem?

Comment: Nothing special in controller, it just has `$scope.selectedItem = null` and the `items` array have been initialized with some static data.

Comment: Can you post what kind of data structure inside element[0].options, may be your getting objects not an array

Comment: This is a problem that has been solved with a single line of code in the newer releases of Angularjs.  Before assuming that you need to go through all the complexity of creating a directive for such a trivial task, perhaps it might be better to consider moving from Angular 1.2.17 (**which was released in *2014!***) to a more recent release.

Comment: @Claies Can you please guide me how can this problem be solved in any latest version of AngularJS?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the **selectedItem** and **items** from the controller to your directive scope, and check the condition and set selectedItem accordingly.

```
angular.module('app').directive('smartSelectDropDown', function(){
 return{
   restrict: 'A',
   replace: true,
   scope: {
  items: '=',
  selectedItem: '=selectedItem'
   }
   link: function(scope){
      if(scope.items.count == 1){
       scope.selectedItem = scope.items[0];
     }
    }
   });
  }
 }
});
```

Though, you might have to modify the code for some corrections as I have not tested it.

**Note**: if you are using directive just for this purpose, then follow @Rangamannar answer.

Comment: Can you please edit my directive and html code to show how it can be done? Also, what is there is a filter placed on `ng-options`?

Comment: check now, if that helps

Comment: This won't work if I have a filter placed on `ng-options`. I have edited my question to show the same.

Comment: Also, the model may be different at each place, so I cannot use `selectedItem: '=selectedItem'` inside the directive

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved without a directive.

**Controller Code changes:**

```
angular.module('app').controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.items = [
                { 
                  id : 1,
                  name : 'Item 1'
                },
                { 
                  id : 2,
                  name : 'Item 2'
                }
              ]
  });
  $scope.selectedItem = items[1]; // or items[0] as per your requirement
```

**HTML Code Changes:**

```
 <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedItem"
      ng-options="item as item.name for item in items track by item.id">
    <!-- You may choose to remove this first option tag with in select -->
    <option value="" ng-bind="Select Item"></option>
 </select>
```

Comment: I need a directive because I will have to use this logic at multiple places in my project if I write this logic in controller. Hence, I prefer a directive so that I need to write the logic at only one place and reuse it in my project. Also, what if there is a filter placed on `ng-options`?

Answer (score 0):

There is even no need of a `directive` in your case, you can just check the `$scope.items` length and assign the first element to `ng-model` if its length is `1`

**Controller:**

```
angular.module('app').controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){
   $scope.selectedItem = null;
   $scope.items = [
    {
        id : 1,
        name : 'Item 1'
    },
    {
        id : 2,
        name : 'Item 2'
    }
    ]
    if($scope.items.length == 1){
        $scope.selectedItem = $scope.items[0];
    }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item as item.name for item in items">
    <option value="" ng-bind="Select Item"></option>
</select>
```

Comment: I need a directive because I will have to use this logic at multiple places in my project if I write this logic in controller. Hence, I prefer a directive so that I need to write the logic at only one place and reuse it in my project. Also, what if there is a filter placed on ng-options?